# What is the right way to test callback invocation using Python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, callback

I have an application code that looks like the following.

```
# Filename: app.py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callback = None

    def set_handler(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def run(self, details):
        name, age = details.split('/')
        if age.isdigit():
            age = int(age)
        else:
            age = -1
        return self.callback(name, age)
```

As you can see, it offers a `set_handler` method to set a callback. The callback must later be invoked with two arguments: a string and an integer. I am trying to ensure this in a unittest.

```
# Filename: test_app.py
import unittest
from app import Foo

class AppTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def f(self, a, b):
        # This callback should get called with the first argument as
        # string and the second argument as integer
        return repr(a) + ',' + repr(b)

    def test_callback(self):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.set_handler(self.f)
        self.assertEqual(foo.run('John/20'), "'John',20")
        self.assertEqual(foo.run('John/xyz'), "'John',-1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This unit test succeeds. But I don't think my way of testing is robust. This unit test is basically a hack because I don't know how to correctly test if a callback has been invoked with the right type of arguments. What I find weird about it is that AppTest's `f` method is sharing the responsibility of type checking by attempting to return a value which are composed of `repr()` of the arguments, and this is not at all robust to say the least.

Could you please help me? Is it possible to relieve the `f` method of the responsibility of testing the types?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try using [`unittest.mock`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock) (standard library on Python 3.3). It allows you to assert how methods were called. For example:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock

from app import Foo

class AppTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_callback(self):
        foo = Foo()
        f = Mock()
        foo.set_handler(f)

        foo.run('John/20')
        f.assert_called_with('John', 20)

        foo.run('John/xyz')
        f.assert_called_with('John', -1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I added another solution that fits your description better.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of thing I wanted.