# is there a preferred way to test callbacks with pytest?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, mocking, pytest

I am unable to find specific examples for testing callbacks using pytest in the docs, google, or here on SO.  I found this: [What is the right way to test callback invocation using Python unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282101); but it's for unittest.  I'm guessing that the monkeypatch functionality of pytest is where I should look but I'm new to automated testing and am looking for an example.

```
def foo(callback):
    callback('Buzz', 'Lightyear')

#--- pytest code ----
def test_foo():
    foo(hello)
    # how do I test that hello was called?
    # how do I test that it was passed the expected arguments?

def hello(first, last):
    return "hello %s %s" % first, last
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is still the same.

You need to replace `hello()` function with a [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class), or, in another words, to "mock" the function.

Then you can use [assert_called_with()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with) to check that it was called with specific arguments you need.

Comment: The Mock documentation specifically states that its intended for use with unittest so I disqualified this solution before posting.  I realize that pytest will work with Mock but I'm looking for a more pytest specific solution.  In general, I would prefer to avoid extra package dependencies.  For reference, http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/: "Mock is very easy to use and is designed for use with unittest."

Comment: @guyja well, `mock` module is, generally speaking, the must-have tool if you want a good coverage or test specific difficult-to-reproduce situations. For mock itself it doesn't really matter what testing framework is used. I've been using `mock` with `nose` for a long time.

Comment: My first reaction to reading the docs for both is that they aim to solve the same set of problems.  If Mock is the standard then when/why should I use pytest's monkeypatch capabilities in place of Mock.

Comment: @guyja as far as I understand, `monkeypatch` is not that powerful as `mock`, `monkeypatch` is mostly for changing global settings, environment variables etc. `Mock` is a standard - that's why it was included in the python standard library in python3. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my working code after applying the answer supplied by @alecxe.

```
def foo(callback):
    callback('Buzz', 'Lightyear')

#--- pytest code ---

import mock

def test_foo():
    func = mock.Mock()

    # pass the mocked function as the callback to foo
    foo(func)

    # test that func was called with the correct arguments
    func.assert_called_with('Buzz', 'Lightyear')
```

Thank you.